# What function in DolphinDB corresponds to choice in Python numpy?

Tags: sampling, dolphindb

For example, I want to generate a sample of 100 elements from the array a = [1, 2, 3, 4] with the probabilities p = [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5] associated with each element in a. In Python I can use `np.random.choice(a=[1, 2, 3, 4], size=100, p=[0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])`.

Does DolphinDB have a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user-defined function:

```
def choice(v, n, p){
        cump = removeTail!([0.0].join(cumsum(p\p.sum())), 1)
        return v[cump.asof(rand(1.0, n))]
}
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
n=100000
p=[0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
r = choice(a, n, p)
```

Starting from version 1.30.19/2.00.7, you can use the built-in function `randDiscrete` directly:

```
randDiscrete(1 2 3 4, [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3], 100)
```

output:

[image]